# Prove that $Enc_{e}(\overline{a}) = \overline{a^e}$ is a one-to-one mapping

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reduced-residue-system

**Task:** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2, e \in \mathbb{Z}, \left( e, \phi(n) \right) = 1$.
Prove that the mapping **$Enc_{e}(\overline{a}) = \overline{a^e}$** mutually unambiguously maps (one-to-one mapping) the $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{n}$ to itself.

**Some clarifications:**

$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{n}$ denotes the reduced residue system modulo n.

$\phi(n)$ - Euler function.

Enc - just a name of mapping (it plays a key role in RSA)

I'd really appreciate any kind of help!